# Prevent page from "jumping" to top on ng-view transitions

Tags: angularjs, css, cordova

I'm trying to implement native-looking view transitions in my Cordova/AngularJS phone application.

I have the sliding effect that I want, with one flaw: when transitioning from a tall view to a shorter one, when the viewport is scrolled beyond the base of the shorter, the scroll position of the view being animated "to" starts off with the top scrolled off the screen. The view then "jumps" properly into position.

[I've made an example - noticeable when transitioning from **Page 2** to **Page 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/9N5pJ/2/).

I'm using the following CSS to transition my views:

```
.view-animate-container {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.3s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.3s;

  display:block;
  width:100%;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.rtl .view-animate.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.rtl .view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.rtl .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.ltr .view-animate.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.ltr .view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.ltr .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

How might I go about preventing the transitioning-from view from scrolling to the top just before my view transition animation starts?

[I've made an example - noticeable when transitioning from **Page 2** to **Page 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/9N5pJ/2/).

Answer (score 1):

on your ng-view div set autoscroll="false"

Comment: Nice simple solution.

Comment: Doesn't work when I apply it to the fiddle provided in the question :/